# error al devolver datos después de event click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, nodejs

### Este es el caso, tengo la siguiente plataforma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

La tabla de la izquierda es generada dinámicamente en función de la fecha seleccionada en la parte superior media, los datos son solicitados a mysql a través de node, usando fetch. 
Al hacer click en uno de los campos, debe llenarse el formulario de la derecha. 
El formulario se completa aprpiadamente con cada campo seleccionado de la primera fecha que se selecciona automáticamente al cargar la página, 
pero después de cambiar de fecha, al hacer click en cualquiera de los nuevos campos generados, éstos no gatillan el click event que sí se alzaba con la fecha inicial en la primera carga (sí, sólo la primera carga, porque si retorno a la fecha inicial después de haber retrocedido y hago click en los campos correspondientes a la fecha inicial, tampoco son grabados los datos en el formulario.

A continuación adjunto el fragmento .js:

```
/*
 * filtrarFechas() se encarga de retornar la fecha actual, siguiente o anterior en los campos,
 * según sea el caso, y llama a otra función que se encarga de llenar los campos.
 * No las adjunté porque funcionan bien independientemente, pero si las necesitan las adjunto
 * de inmediato.

*/

(async($)=>{
    const json          = await obtenJson(); // obtengo registros de la tabla
    const fechaReciente = json[0].fecha.slice(0, 10);
    const fechaAntigua  = json[json.length-1].fecha.slice(0, 10);
    var fecha = fechaReciente;
    fecha     = await filtrarFechas(fecha, fechaReciente, fechaAntigua, json, 0); // devuelve los datos de la fecha actual, la más reciente
    $('.left').click(async()  => {
        resetFields();
        fecha = await filtrarFechas(fecha, fechaReciente, fechaAntigua, json, -1); // devuelve los datos de la fecha anterior en los registros
    });
    $('.right').click(async() => {
        resetFields();
        fecha = await filtrarFechas(fecha, fechaReciente, fechaAntigua, json, 1); // devuelve los datos de la fecha siguiente en los registros
    });
})(jQuery);
```

---

Les agradezco de antemano!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probablemente sea porque se pierden los eventos, cuando recreas la tabla tambien estas recreando los nodos, esto quiere decir que las referencias a los eventos no existen aun. Puedes bindear los eventos a un elemento como el document para que las referencias a los elementos no se pierdan cuando recreas la tabla

```
$(document).on( 'click', 'tr', function() {
  // Tu función aqui
});
```

Documentacion de jQuery https://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Desgraciadamente, tampoco funciona, los eventos se siguen perdiendo

Comment: Me retracto! Puede hacerlo funciona con tu método, gracias!